# How to assess the relationship between a continuous explanatory and categorical response variable?

Tags: correlation, multinomial-distribution, supervised-learning

I have a categorical variable as my response variable (severity of disease: absent, mild, mild/moderate, moderate, moderate/severe, severe), and I have a continuous variable (test scores, which are normally distributed). I'm interesting in seeing how the test score is associated with the severity of the disease. I thought of a few approaches: 1) multinomial logistic regression 2) correlation analysis (but I have no idea which technique to use).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the outcome of interest is ordered I would suggest 3) Proportional odds logistic regression (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logistic_regression).